# How to make nodejs generate an xcode project

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, xcode, cordova

I am trying to figure out if there is a way I can make an npm package that generates an ios xcode template project but have the project files renamed to the specified name, along with things like the application name being changed.

I have been researching this for a while and I cant find a clear answer on how I can achieve this.

I am trying to achieve the functionality that something like apache cordova has where it generates the ios project when running "cordova platform add ios"

How can I make something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I can just use something like what this [tutorial](https://medium.com/northcoders/creating-a-project-generator-with-node-29e13b3cd309) describes. instead of a javascript project being generated I can just use an xcode project and edit the properties of the project during generation.